# Image processing: Trying to make a photo negative?

Tags: python

I understand to make an image negative, you have to change the RGB values so that the current value is being subtracted from 255.

What is wrong with my following code?

```
def negative(im):
height=len(im)
width = len(im[0])
for row in range(height):
    for col in range(width):
        red = im[row][col][0] - 255
        green = im[row][col][1] - 255
        blue = im[row][col][2] - 255
        im[row][col]=[red,green,blue]
return im
```

It returns the error "TclError: can't parse color "#-1d-c-2""

Comment: `255 - im[row][col][0]`

Comment: indent properly first of all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you are getting negative numbers. I think you should be doing `255 - x` rather than `x - 255`

Comment: Just noticed this was given as a comment by @grc

Answer (score 3):

Why not use scikit-image instead?  It's vectorized:

```
from skimage.io import imread

image = imread(image)
negative = 255 - image
```